# OpenGL(with GLSL) using glTexBuffer and texelFetch

Tags: opengl

Trying to render a rectangle in OpenGL desktop, but the internal Format used in `glTexBuffer(...)` and respective code for `texelFetch(...)` is not working for me. I have the correct primitive rendering, need to correct the texture buffer part only. Below is the relevant code snippet

---

```
unsigned char texData [16] = 
    { 
        255, 0, 0, 0, //Red 
        0,255,0,255, //Green 
        0,0,255,255, //Blue 
        255,0,255,255, //PINK
    }; 
    glGenBuffers( 2,texBuffObj);
    glBindBuffer( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,texBuffObj[0]);
    glBufferData( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,sizeof(texData),texData,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, textureID);
    glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,GL_RGBA8UI,texBuffObj[0]);
Fragement Shader Snippet:
```

#version 330 core
uniform usamplerBuffer samplerTexBuffer;
out vec4 color;
in vec2 vs_texCoord;
in vec3 vert_Color;
void main()        
{
    int offset = 8; // 0:RED 4:GREEN 8:BLUE 12:PINK
    vec4 colBuff;
    colBuff = texelFetch(samplerTexBuffer,offset) ;
    color = colBuff;
}

---

The required rendering is such that with :

> offset value **0** primitive color : 255, 0,   0,   0,     //Red
>   offset value **4** primitive color : 0,   255, 0,   255,   //Green
>   offset value **8** primitive color : 0,   0,   255, 255,   //Blue
>   offset value **12** primitive color : 255, 0,   255, 255,   //PINK

---

What are the necessary corrections required ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`texelFetch` takes texel coordinates, not a byte offset into the buffer. Since your texels are 4 bytes wide, you want to retrieve them using indices 0, 1, 2, 3 rather than 0, 4, 8, 12.

Comment: It worked ! what confuses me is the enum value and the respective texData, can I assume that for GL_R32F the texData should be a float array where each element will provide the R value only ?

Comment: @ppu That is correct, and you would still fetch texels using texel coordinates (0 for the texel with your first red value, 1 for the texel with your second red value, etc.)